# Heroku displaying full Rails error page even though config.consider_all_requests_local = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Even though my config for production reads

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

But I am still getting the rails error messages in production. No idea why.

This only started happening recently. It was fine for a while.

I'm using Puma, which I recently switched to. That may have caused the problems but I don't know why. Here is my puma.rb config file

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'production'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: Are you sure your app is running on production environment?

Comment: I believe so, unless there is something I am missing. In the heroku config I have RACK_ENV: production, RAILS_ENV: production and I had this thought so I modified consider_all_requests_local for the development environment and pushed and still go the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was stupid. I finally realized that I had accidentally copied the development.rb file to some other directory in my code (actually two different directories) so the dev config was being read in production and mucking everything up. Thank god I finally noticed that. I had pulled my hair out and written a bunch of custom error catches in the meantime.

I think this was also slowing down each request as well. God I'm glad I figured this out.